# Create dynamic paths in AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, partitioning, emr

I have a bunch of files in s3 in the following path example:

```
s3://bucket/date=2016-01-02/2016-01-02_1012_582.txt
s3://bucket/date=2016-01-07/2016-01-07_1415_272.txt
```

When the files were originally put in, the partition, in this case the date, was kept simple because it was quick. Now, I want to partition based on the file names.

So, the two paths would be these:

```
s3://bucket/data/date=2016-01-02/a=1012/b=582/2016-01-02_1012_582.txt
s3://bucket/data/date=2016-01-07/a=1415/b=272/2016-01-07_1012_272.txt
```

Is there any clever way I could do this without reprocessing the files? I've looked at the aws cli, but this doesn't seem to be part of it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would have to write a script to take each file and copy or move them to the new key.